# How do I get information from a DOM object from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently modifying a website, I need to get the current slide's class name, and modify the img tag
after run

```
var test=document.getElementsByClassName("activeslide");
```

it give the value of test

```
[<li class="slide-4 activeslide" style="visibility: visible; opacity:1;">         ]
    <a target="_blank">
        <img src="img/floorplans/suite-A.jpg" style="height: 560px; width: 495px; left:132px; top:0px">
    </a>
</li>
```

how do I get the slide-4 and how do I edit the img tag by DOM? I tried to do test.innerHTML, and tried to convert test into string, test.toString(); but it returns me "[object HTMLCollection]"

Comment: *"but it returns me "[object HTMLCollection]""* As the name suggets, `getElement` **`s`** `ByClassName` returns a *list* of elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`myElement.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) or [`myElement.getAttribute("class")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) where `myElement` is a reference to your element. Newer browsers also have [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList).

Comment: The `test` var in your example is an array. You cannot call `.className()` on an array, you can only call that function on a single element. To use the methods as specified by Bjorn above, access a specific item in your array: f.e. `test[0].className()`.

Comment: Just FYI, `className` is not a function, it's a property, use it as `test[0].className` not `test[0].className()`

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array. Following code will give you the img DOM element:

```
var liArray = document.getElementsByClassName("activeslide");
var imgArray = liArray[0].getElementsByTagName("img");
var img = imgArray[0];
```